# Is it possible to make SwiftUIPager scroll the icons with the newest version?

Tags: swiftui

https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#ui-customization

After the final update of the `SwiftUIPager` with `Podfile` stopped to scroll!
Added the `loopPages()`.Today, before I had updated the SwiftUIPager - it worked. Now it runs without scrolling left/right.Are there any solutions?

```
Pager(page: self.$page2,                                
data: self.data,                                
id: \.self) {                                
self.pageView($0)                        
}                                                
.itemSpacing(self.buttonPadding)                        
.horizontal(.leftToRight)                        
.interactive(0.6)                        
.itemAspectRatio(1.0)                        
.loopPages()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Try changing your implementation of `func pageView(_ page: Int) -> some View`:

*The idea is to replace the `button` items in the `pageView` with `Image`*

```
// MARK: - Page class for Scroll View - Levels icons

func pageView(_ page: Int) -> some View {
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: LobbyView.levels[page] )!)
    .renderingMode(.original)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation{
          // the same action button does
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2**
If not, go to line 169 inside `Pager.swift` (Pod framework):
[image]

and swap

```
wrappedView = AnyView(wrappedView.gesture(allowsDragging ? swipeGesture : nil))
```

with

```
wrappedView = AnyView(wrappedView.highPriorityGesture(allowsDragging ? swipeGesture : nil))
```

> I'd go for option 1. Notice in option 2 if you do this, any gesture
>   you add inside your page content won't be recognized.
>
> Fernando Moya de Rivas